# Ruby on Rails - global variable persistence across requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a RoR application, I would like to load a set of key/values from db into a global variable which persists across requests and clear the variable as and when I need. My application runs in a WAS cluster. I tried a few things. 1. Used memcachestore and read/write/clear as needed. 2. Load the key/values in a yaml file and clear it when required. Please let me know if I could do it differently.Thanks.

Comment: Old question..but maybe you can fix it with redis as key-value store? you could find more information here: http://redis.io/

Answer (score 0):

Don't we have flash and session hashes which can store any object we need?